# Filter react component from navbar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Im'm trying to implement a search bar in my nav bar that will bring me a list of cities and according to the selected city it has to update the list of offers in the main page,since the offers is filtered by cities, the thing is, the navbar is one component and the offers is in another component, if I search for a city in my navbar and hit enter, how can the offer component listen to it and make the call to the api based by the searched city? here is my code:

**Navbar:**

```
class NavigationBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.cityoffer = this.cityoffer.bind(this);
  }


  cityoffer(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.history.push("/home");
    console.log("cities");
  }



  render(){
    const { isAuthenticated } = this.props.auth;

    const userLinks = (
      <form className="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 ml-auto" onSubmit={this.cityoffer}>
      <input className="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Cidade" aria-label="Search"/>
      <button className="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Procurar</button>

      </form>

    );

    const guestLinks = (
      <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li className="nav-item">
            <Link to="/login" className="nav-link">Entrar</Link>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
            <Link to="/signup" className="nav-link">Registrar</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    );

    return (
      <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <button className="navbar-brand brandbutton" onClick={this.brand}><img src={imglogo} className="imagemNav" alt="logo"/></button>
        <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div className="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-3 dual-collapse2" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
          { isAuthenticated ? userLinks : guestLinks }
        </div>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}

NavigationBar.propTypes = {
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  logout: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    auth: state.auth
  };
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, { logout })(NavigationBar));
```

**Offers:**

```
class Anuncios extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      city: 2958,
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps = (nextProps)  => {
    console.log(nextProps)
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    this.props.fetchAnuncios(this.state.city);


  }
  render() {

    return (
      <div className="pagemargin">

      <AnunciosList anuncios={this.props.anuncios}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Anuncios.propTypes = {
  anuncios: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  fetchAnuncios: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    anuncios: state.anuncios
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchAnuncios, searchCidadesRequestID})(Anuncios);
```

**App:**

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <NavigationBar />
        <FlashMessagesList/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**routes:**

```
const AppRouter = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <AlertProvider template={AlertTemplate} {...options}>
      <App/>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Intro}/>
        <Route path="/home" component={Home}/>
        <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp}/>
        <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage}/>
        <Route path="/filtrar" component={Filtrar}/>
        <Route path="/cupons" component={requireAuth(Cupons)}/>
        <Route path="/perfil" component={requireAuth(Perfil)}/>
        <Route path="/anuncio/:id" component={AnuncioDetalhes}/>
        <Route component={NoMatch}/>
      </Switch>
      </AlertProvider>
    </div>
  </Router>
);
```

**like that:**

[image]